# Update a field value in model Django Rest

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

> `serializers.SerializerMethodField()` is only meant to read value ie
> retrieve, it will not update the lang value.

I want to create an API that can update a field value. Mainly, I want to change the field `lang` in the `User` model. Here is my code

`models.py`

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  member_since = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
  lang = models.CharField(max_length = 5, default = 'en')
  def get_lang(self):
        return self.lang
```

`serializers.py`

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

class ProfileRetrieveUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  member_since = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
  lang = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
  class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'member_since','lang'
        ]
  def get_member_since(self, obj):
              return obj.profile.member_since.date()
  def get_lang(self, obj):
      return obj.profile.get_lang()
  def update(self, instance, validated_data):
      print(validated_data)
      setattr(instance.profile, "lang", validated_data.get("lang",instance.profile.lang))
      instance.save()
      return instance
```

`views.py`

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from .serializers import (
    CurrentUserDetailSerializer, ProfileRetrieveUpdateSerializer,
    UserLoginSerializer, UserSerializerWithToken,
)

User = get_user_model()

class ProfileRetrieveUpdateAPIView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    """
    View that returns user profile data.
    """
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileRetrieveUpdateSerializer
    lookup_field = 'username'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'username'
```

`axios.patch(url, {'lang': 'fr')` (additional, I don't think it's wrong here)

When I call API, I get that the `validated_data` value is `{}`!

I think the problem is in the `serializers.py` module.

Comment: `serializers.SerializerMethodField()` is only meant to read `lang` value i.e retrieve, it will not update `lang` value.

Comment: Yes, i try to fix it to `lang` = serializers.Charfield(source = get_lang) but it did not work

Comment: remove `source=get_lang`.

Comment: got error: `AttributeError at /api/users/profile/user_0/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field "lang" on serializer "ProfileRetrieveUpdateSerializer".
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the "User" instance.
Original exception text was: 'User' object has no attribute 'lang'.`

Comment: can you also include the post data that you're sending to API?

Comment: the prolem is `serializers.SerializerMethodField()`, tho.
anyway: `axios.patch(/api/users/profile/user_0/, {'lang': 'fr')`

Comment: `axios.patch(/api/users/profile/user_0/, {'lang': 'fr'})` there was an `}` missing.

Comment: ya, i know, typing mistake. The problem isnot it.

Comment: your serializer is still old can you update the code in your serializer.

Answer (score 0):

```
lang = serializers.CharField(source = 'get_lang') 

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        setattr(instance.profile, "lang", validated_data.get("get_lang"))
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

reason: `serializers.SerializerMethodField()` is only meant to read value ie retrieve, it will not update `lang` value.